# How to query hierarchical data as XML

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
      COL1 COL2             COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         T1 Direct              M1
         T1 Direct              M2
         T1 List                M3
         M3 Direct              M4
         M3 Direct              M5
         M3 List                M6
         M6 Direct              M7
         M6 Direct              M8
         T2 Direct              M9
```

Col2 - 'Direct' says that a Col3 is a direct child to Col1.

Col2 - 'List' says that that Col3 is a sub-list to Col1.

So for above example, T1 is having M1,M2 as direct children and M3 is a sub-child. And again, M3 is having M4,M5 direct children and M6 as a sub-child. And it goes on.

I need above to be converted to XML like below using Oracle query.

```
 <ROOT>
 <T1>
    <M1/>
    <M2/>
    <M3>
       <M4/>
       <M5/>
       <M6>
         <M7/>
         <M8/>
       <M6/>
    <M3/>
 <T1/>
 <T2>
   <M9 />
 <T2>
 </ROOT>
```

How can I get that XML result as above? I'm allowed to add additional entries to table in order to keep whole xml in a `<ROOT>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

XML node names can't start with a number, so the output you've shown isn't valid. You can get the structure with different names, or with attributes using those values instead.

Start with a query that gets the hierarchy (`col2` seems to be irrelevant here, it's just describing the hierarchy that exists just from `col1` and `col3`):

```
select lpad(' ', level) || col3
from t42
connect by col1 = prior col3 and col1 != col3
start with col1 = col3;

LPAD('',LEVEL)||COL3                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1                                                                              
  2                                                                             
  3                                                                             
   4                                                                            
   5                                                                            
   6                                                                            
    7                                                                           
    8
```

You can then turn those into XML elements, in this case preceding with a fixed character to make them valid names:

```
select level, xmlelement(evalname 'x' || col3)
from t42
connect by col1 = prior col3 and col1 != col3
start with col1 = col3;

     LEVEL XMLELEMENT(EVALNAME'X'||COL3)                                             
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 <x1></x1>
         2 <x2></x2>
         2 <x3></x3>
         3 <x4></x4>
         3 <x5></x5>
         3 <x6></x6>
         4 <x7></x7>
         4 <x8></x8>
```

And you can then use that query in a [`dbms_xmlgen.newContextFromHierarchy` call](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb13gen.htm#sthref1338):

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(
  dbms_xmlgen.newcontextfromhierarchy(
    q'[select level, xmlelement(evalname 'x' || col3)
      from t42
      connect by col1 = prior col3 and col1 != col3
      start with col1 = col3]')) as result
from dual;

RESULT                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x1>
  <x2/>
  <x3>
    <x4/>
    <x5/>
    <x6>
      <x7/>
      <x8/>
    </x6>
  </x3>
</x1>
```

Or as attributes:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(
  dbms_xmlgen.newcontextfromhierarchy(
    q'[select level,
        xmlelement("x", xmlattributes(level as "level", col3 as "col3"))
      from t42
      connect by col1 = prior col3 and col1 != col3
      start with col1 = col3]')) as result
from dual;

RESULT                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x level="1" col3="1">
  <x level="2" col3="2"/>
  <x level="2" col3="3">
    <x level="3" col3="4"/>
    <x level="3" col3="5"/>
    <x level="3" col3="6">
      <x level="4" col3="7"/>
      <x level="4" col3="8"/>
    </x>
  </x>
</x>
```

If you really wanted to you could convert the first version to a string and strip out the dummy character:

```
select replace(
  dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(
    dbms_xmlgen.newcontextfromhierarchy(
      q'[select level, xmlelement(evalname 'x' || col3)
        from t42
        connect by col1 = prior col3 and col1 != col3
        start with col1 = col3]')).getstringval(),
  'x', null) as result
from dual;

RESULT                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?ml version="1.0"?>                                                            
<1>                                                                             
  <2/>                                                                          
  <3>                                                                           
    <4/>                                                                        
    <5/>                                                                        
    <6>                                                                         
      <7/>                                                                      
      <8/>                                                                      
    </6>                                                                        
  </3>                                                                          
</1>
```

Or an equivalent with `getclobval()` for a large document. But that is now a string, not real XML; if you tried to convert that back to an XMLType you'd get an error like "LPX-00231: invalid character 49 ('1') found in a Name or Nmtoken". You may have something that will accept that anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt help. How ever I now understand the problem with my question and corrected above. Can you please help in further?